# Spring Compatibility with Hibernate 4.1.9

Tags: spring, hibernate, compatibility

I upgraded my project with the latest spring and hibernate releases (spring 3.2.1 and hibernate 4.1.9) but they seem to be incompatible. One of the changes are part of spring's jdbc framework.

```
public <T> T execute(StatementCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException {
    Assert.notNull(action, "Callback object must not be null");

    Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(getDataSource());
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Connection conToUse = con;
        if (this.nativeJdbcExtractor != null &&
                this.nativeJdbcExtractor.isNativeConnectionNecessaryForNativeStatements()) {
            conToUse = this.nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativeConnection(con);
        }
        stmt = conToUse.createStatement();
        applyStatementSettings(stmt);
        Statement stmtToUse = stmt;
        if (this.nativeJdbcExtractor != null) {
            stmtToUse = this.nativeJdbcExtractor.getNativeStatement(stmt);
        }
        T result = action.doInStatement(stmtToUse);
        handleWarnings(stmt);
        return result;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        // Release Connection early, to avoid potential connection pool deadlock
        // in the case when the exception translator hasn't been initialized yet.
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
        stmt = null;
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
        con = null;
        throw getExceptionTranslator().translate("StatementCallback", getSql(action), ex);
    }
    finally {
        JdbcUtils.closeStatement(stmt);
        DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(con, getDataSource());
    }
```

Hibernate 4.1.9 now proxies jdbc statements and the exception converter now kicks in which throws a runtime exception instead of a checked one. For e.g. Instead of SQLException now a runtime exception is thrown - SQLGrammerException.

Spring probably should be handling this hibernate change, right?

**Edit**

I discussed on hibernate forums, hibernate jira forums & on the [dev mailing list](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/hibernate-dev/2013-February/009399.html). They claim that since this is a major release (4.x) such compatibility issues are expected. They ask the clients to update their code to resolve the issue.

I have posted the same issue on the [spring jira forum](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10267) and currently its under discussion.

I wonder how others are working around this problem!

Comment: How is the above code related to Hibernate? I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Hibernate 4.1.9 proxies jdbc statements (which was not done in the earlier versions at least 3.6). The proxy throws runtime exception instead of checked exception (SQLGrammerException instead of SQLException). Since a runtime exception is thrown, the code in the catch block (above) never gets executed. Does that help ?

Comment: Not really. Hibernate statements will never be executed using Spring's JDBC template anyway, so where's the problem?

Comment: We use JPA (HibernateJPADialect & JpaTransactionManager) as an abstraction layer over hibernate. Spring binds the data source resource with the connection handle create through hibernate jpa dialect. This mean any request to create a connection gets delegated to hibernate which proxies connections and statements. Hence when a connection is requested for executing a query through spring's jdbc template we get a proxied connection.

Comment: Hibernate, and your JDBC code, should get connections from a Spring DataSource, instead of having Spring get connections from Hibernate. And why do you use JDBC in the first place, since you're using JPA? Use JPQL queries and, if really necessary, JPA native queries.

Comment: The application uses a combination of JPA and JDBC. For mapped entities JPA is used (included JPQL queries) while for non mapped objects direct JDBC is used. How do you configure spring to create connections without delegating it to hibernate? I debugged with the old hibernate version (3.6.0). It did the same thing. The only difference in the new version of hibernate is that it proxies statements.

Comment: You declare a Spring DataSource bean (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#jdbc-connections) and use this DataSource bean in the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#orm-jpa-setup-lcemfb)

Comment: I have done that but have a look at the jdbcTemplate code for getting a connection. It gets it from the TransactionSynchronizationManager which gives it a hibernate mapped one because we use JpaTransactionManager.

Comment: Ah, OK. Now I understand the problem. I don't have any solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring agrees to add a patch for this. [Probably in 4.x](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10267). One of the workaround mentioned right now is

> For the time being, a good solution might be to define a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor and to mark your JDBC-accessing classes with the @Repository annotation. This will autodetect your Hibernate LocalSessionFactoryBean and use it to translate exceptions based on the Hibernate exception hierarchy, as thrown from JDBC calls in your case. That very same post-processor is also applicable to Hibernate API usage (i.e. sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() usage in your Hibernate-accessing classes)

I have not tried this out since it might not be practical in our case to mark all the jdbc accessing classes with @Repository annotation.